# Let's get critical: Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Setting up the Raspberry as a data logger](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7224/setting-up-the-raspberry-as-a-data-logger)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Python Synth with Raspberry](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/python-synth-with-raspberry)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Which key types the "|" symbol?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7479/which-key-types-the-symbol)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [How long does it take to perform the initial update?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7344/how-long-does-it-take-to-perform-the-initial-update)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Arch | SSH fail on reboot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7132/arch-ssh-fail-on-reboot)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How is root directory mounted on Arch?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7287/how-is-root-directory-mounted-on-arch)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [SSH and rsa authentication on mpich2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7384/ssh-and-rsa-authentication-on-mpich2)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Setting up Bluetooth dongle](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/setting-up-bluetooth-dongle)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Play video in full screen with USB Audio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7246/play-video-in-full-screen-with-usb-audio)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [What is the "AP" on the Raspberry Pi, from the FAQ?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/what-is-the-ap-on-the-raspberry-pi-from-the-faq)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a host of questions about keyboard layouts that should have been closed as off-topic.

Strange they weren't flagged and they managed to slip through the filter.