# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Options for a kid to write a 3D game in Python?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8511/options-for-a-kid-to-write-a-3d-game-in-python)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [100% processor usage with WHILE loop in Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/100-processor-usage-with-while-loop-in-raspberry-pi)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Why won't Razer Naga Epic work with Raspberry Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8500/why-wont-razer-naga-epic-work-with-raspberry-pi)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Pidora - can't install cheese](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/pidora-cant-install-cheese)

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 7)
- [Can you transfer data through the microUSB?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/can-you-transfer-data-through-the-microusb)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [isc-dhcp-server install and run problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8614/isc-dhcp-server-install-and-run-problem)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Cannot mkdir unless sudo is used](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8992/cannot-mkdir-unless-sudo)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Resize file system on OpenELEC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/resize-file-system-on-openelec)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Raspberry on Node.js - Spawns 5 node process on first page request](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8815/raspberry-on-node-js-spawns-5-node-process-on-first-page-request)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Default kernel preemption vs real time patch?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8970/default-kernel-preemption-vs-real-time-patch)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

Answer (score 1):

A few notes on this eval:

First, by and large this site looks... Good!

That said, the community here is a bit bottom-heavy: lots of questions from folks who don't/can't stick around to share their knowledge. The core community is heavily engaged, but not yet large enough to sustain the site. It reminds me a lot of [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) back when we launched that.

Finally, a problem y'all have struggled with since the early beta: questions on topics that aren't clearly RasPI related. This arises naturally due to the tendency for hobbyists with little prior programming / Linux / computer experience to jump in and get stuck on basic tasks - it's not *necessarily* a problem, but it *could* become one. [Jivings noted](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375/lets-get-critical-jun-2013-site-self-evaluation/376#376) during the last eval that some off-topic questions were getting overlooked... That's been the case this time around as well.

The core community here is growing, but not yet large enough to graduate; still, I have high hopes for this site in the future.